# Prove by induction that this sum is not a natural number.

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} +...+\frac{1}{n}$ for any $1<n$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Without induction: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}=k$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n!}{i}=kn!$. By [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) exists a prime $n/2<p<n$. But $p$ divides everything except $n!/p$, contradiction.

Comment: @user236182 "It is a very strange phenomenon that many problem books seem to push the Bertrand's Postulate solution to this problem. I remember that this came up as a problem (apropos of nothing) in my freshman year math class, and I had some problem book at hand and duly turned in a solution which used BP. The next year I got the problem in a number theory course and by then was sophisticated enough to see the elementary solution involving the ord_2 function. –  Pete L. Clark Aug 19 '10 at 0:04"